# Notepad++ replace dash between two random letters without spaces?

Tags: notepad++, css

I need to replace some CSS classes from dash to underscore (`-` to `_`)

Example:

```
.a-2Vndt-.wrapper-1VLyxH, .people-u6dGxF.active-2UF8Zh, .ListItem-u6dGxF:hover, .ListItem-u6dGxF { }
```

As you can see, the letters on the sides (or outside) the dashes are random and not the same and have no spaces. They need to be turned into underscores. There are dashes within the document that do *not* need to be changed as well. So, a general replace will destroy rather than fix it. Does anyone know how I can replace the dashes between all random characters, throughout the document—and only those dashes—into underscores?

*Change*: `.people-u6dGxF` becomes `.people_u6dGxF`, or `.user2-hx` becomes `.user2_hx`

*Leave Alone*: Dashes with spaces in front of or behind `-` ,  `-`, or double `--`.

Snippet of text that is being modified:

```
/* -- Complications and Combinations -- */
.compact-2Nkcau .timestamp-p1Df1m, .cozy-VmLDNB .timestamp-p1Df1m.alt-1dvXnH, .edited-1v5nT8 {
    font-family: Helvetica !important;
    font-size: 9px !important;
    width: 48px;
}
/* -- This CSS document is very large and will require multiple passes -- */
.text-sm-medium-3Pz3rB, .text-sm-1-3Zj3Iv {
    font-family: Helvetica !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you used regex or find and replace, how would you know which `-` to leave as `-`?

Comment: I believe dashes between all random characters means between any letters? Is that correct @Jake J?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1815042/edit) and add expected result for your example.

Comment: "There are dashes within the document that do not need to be changed" - which ones?

Comment: @A-Tech Yes, that is correct. So any dash that is between randomletter-randomletter should be replaced with randomletter_randomletter, however dashes by themselves should remain. Example: -1, -2, Hello--!. It is literally only the dashes between two characters (a-1, or a-a) without spaces that should be changed.

Comment: In your example, which ones must be replaced and which ones mustn't? Give the expected result for your example.

Comment: And you will replace `font-family` by `font_family`, are you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few regexes that you could use depending on how you define character. If you mean characters of the alphabet, use. `(?<=[A-Za-z])-(?=[A-Za-z])`to find any - between any letters.

`(?<=[A-Za-z])` Looks for any alphabetic letter ahead of our target*

`-` is our target

`(?=[A-Za-z])` Looks for any letter after our target*

If numbers are to be considered as well, they can be added to our look-ahead and look-behind target. For that change `[A-Za-z]` to `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

`(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])-(?=[A-Za-z0-9])` is our new expression.

If you want *any* character that is not whitespace use `(?<=[^ ])-(?=[^ ])`. It is the same as above, but instead of wrapping our target by letters of the alphabet `[A-Za-z]` we surround it by anything that is not whitespace `[^ ]`.

---

* See also [this forum thread](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/post/66924) for more about looking around a word/character group.

There is also a general [GitHub documentation](https://gist.github.com/ramons03/6152802) for Notepad++ advanced search.

Comment: This `(?<=[A-Za-z])-(?=[A-Za-z])` is very close, however, if dash is between letter and number (i.e. a-1) the dash is ignored. `(?<=[^ ])-(?=[^ ])` doesn't work because it will grab double dash `--`.

Comment: @JakeJ now better?

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to replace only dashes when inside class names.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\.|\G)\w+\K-`
- Replace with: `_`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
    \.          # a dot
  |           # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
)           # end group
\w+         # 1 or more word characters
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
-           # a dash
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]